# How to use a nib to configure DetailViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have multiple cells in a table referring to the same DetailViewController. How can I use nibs to be redirected to the same DetailViewControllers with different content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected indexPath by this method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

From this method you can load the DetailViewController by this,

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *tableViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:tableViewNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In the above method you can assign values what you want to change when you select different cells.

Comment: Do I have to include this code inside the curly braces? How does this work?

Comment: yes you have to add the 2nd set of code inside that 1st method.

Comment: Doing that causes a Thread 1: SIGABRT when I click on a table cell.

Comment: Make sure your DetailViewController work correctly. or are you using Storyboard??

Comment: I think I am using storyboard

Comment: Then you don't have to add the 2nd code. just control drag the cell to the DetailViewController.

Comment: But how to view a different view on my DetailViewController now when I tap on different cells?

Comment: You have to set the DetailViewController content inside that method. indexPath.row will give you the selected cell.